# How to visualize 3 phase currents vector diagram

Tags: microcontroller, brushless-dc-motor

I want to visualize the 3 phase currents which are 120 degrees apart by vector diagrams and calculate the net current vector and hence the net magnetic flux vector. The application is the PMSM motor and what i want to do is continuously capture the stator phase currents and draw magnetic flux vectors on abc axis. Please advise on what tools can i use. What programming language i can use. This will be the first step in coverting from abc axis to alpha beta axis.

Comment: You can use any programming language.  Matlab or Python might be better than say COBOL, but  it's really not clear what you want to do.  Are you planning to "capture" the phase currents with A/D converters and try to plot the space vector in real time?  Or is this all simulation?

Comment: I am not getting the expected output. I want to record the data using A/D converter and offline i want to see if i am getting expected result. Still more of understanding.